# Mysql Query optimization, Move a CASE Exists (SELECT...) into a left join

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

**Update**
Here is the ddl of the two tables that the CASE statement uses

```
CREATE TABLE product_option (
merchant_id                 smallint unsigned NOT NULL,
product_option_id           smallint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
product_option_name         varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
product_id                  int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,    /* Option may be associated with a product  */
package_id                  int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,    /* or all products with this package    */
PRIMARY KEY pk_product_option (merchant_id,product_option_id),

) TYPE=MyISAM PACK_KEYS=1 COMMENT='Options';

CREATE TABLE package_2_product (
merchant_id     smallint unsigned NOT NULL,
package_id      int unsigned NOT NULL,
product_id      int unsigned NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY pk_package_2_product (merchant_id,package_id,product_id)

) TYPE=MyISAM PACK_KEYS=1 COMMENT='Link product to package';
```

I have a query...

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
  p.*,
  CASE p.in_stock_msg  WHEN '' THEN 'In stock' ELSE p.in_stock_msg  END AS in_stock_msg, 
  CASE p.out_stock_msg WHEN '' THEN ''         ELSE p.out_stock_msg END AS out_stock_msg,
  CASE WHEN EXISTS (
    SELECT product_option_id 
      FROM product_option
     WHERE merchant_id = 116 AND product_id = p.product_id
     UNION
    SELECT product_id FROM package_2_product
     WHERE merchant_id = 116 AND product_id = p.product_id
  ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS options_exist,
  i.thumbnail,i.thumbnail_width,i.thumbnail_height,
  i.title AS thumbnail_title, i.alt AS thumbnail_alt
FROM 
  product p 
  INNER JOIN category_2_product c2p ON p.merchant_id=c2p.merchant_id 
                                       AND p.product_id=c2p.product_id 
                                       AND c2p.category_id = 84
  LEFT  JOIN product_image        i ON p.merchant_id = i.merchant_id
                                       AND p.product_id = i.product_id
                                       AND i.is_default = 1 
WHERE 
  p.merchant_id = 116
  AND FIND_IN_SET('live',p.param) > 0
  AND FIND_IN_SET('wholesale-only',p.param) = 0
ORDER BY
  p.rank, p.product_name
LIMIT 0, 50;
```

The pertinent part being the CASE WHEN EXISTS...
is causing the query to take multiple seconds to run.  Without the sub-select it finishes in a tenth of a second.

I'm wondering if there is a way to move this type of case, sub-select into an inner join to get the same data, and not have the sub-select run for every row that gets returned.

Attempting the below query with a tweak to the Coalesce line and the LEFT JOIN (SELECT...) p1

I received this error...

Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'p1.product_id' in 'on clause'

Here is the query...

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
  p.*,
  CASE p.in_stock_msg  WHEN '' THEN 'In stock' ELSE p.in_stock_msg  END AS in_stock_msg,  
  CASE p.out_stock_msg WHEN '' THEN ''         ELSE p.out_stock_msg END AS out_stock_msg,
  COALESCE(p1.product_option_id, p2.product_id) IS NOT NULL AS options_exist,
  i.thumbnail,i.thumbnail_width,i.thumbnail_height,
  i.title AS thumbnail_title, i.alt AS thumbnail_alt
FROM 
  product p 
  INNER JOIN category_2_product c2p ON p.merchant_id=c2p.merchant_id 
                                       AND p.product_id=c2p.product_id 
                                       AND c2p.category_id = 84
  LEFT  JOIN product_image        i ON p.merchant_id = i.merchant_id
                                       AND p.product_id = i.product_id
                                       AND i.is_default = 1 
  LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT product_option_id
     FROM product_option
    WHERE merchant_id = 116
    GROUP BY product_id) p1 on p1.product_id = p.product_id
   LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT product_id
    FROM package_2_product
   WHERE merchant_id = 116
    GROUP BY product_id) p2 on p1.product_id is null and p2.product_id = p.product_id 
WHERE 
  p.merchant_id = 116
  AND FIND_IN_SET('live',p.param) > 0
  AND FIND_IN_SET('wholesale-only',p.param) = 0
ORDER BY
  p.rank, p.product_name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
  p.*,
  CASE p.in_stock_msg  WHEN '' THEN 'In stock' ELSE p.in_stock_msg  END AS in_stock_msg, 
  CASE p.out_stock_msg WHEN '' THEN ''         ELSE p.out_stock_msg END AS out_stock_msg,
  COALESCE(p1.product_id, p2.product_id) IS NOT NULL AS options_exist,
  i.thumbnail,i.thumbnail_width,i.thumbnail_height,
  i.title AS thumbnail_title, i.alt AS thumbnail_alt
FROM 
  product p 
  INNER JOIN category_2_product c2p ON p.merchant_id=c2p.merchant_id 
                                       AND p.product_id=c2p.product_id 
                                       AND c2p.category_id = 84
  LEFT  JOIN product_image        i ON p.merchant_id = i.merchant_id
                                       AND p.product_id = i.product_id
                                       AND i.is_default = 1 
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT product_id
      FROM product_option
     WHERE merchant_id = 116
     GROUP BY product_id) p1 on p1.product_id = p.product_id
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT product_id
      FROM package_2_product
     WHERE merchant_id = 116
     GROUP BY product_id) p2 on p1.product_id is null and p2.product_id = p.product_id

WHERE 
  p.merchant_id = 116
  AND FIND_IN_SET('live',p.param) > 0
  AND FIND_IN_SET('wholesale-only',p.param) = 0
ORDER BY
  p.rank, p.product_name
```

Notes:

- `on p1.product_id is null` is added to the 2nd left join to prevent it being executed when p1 already has a result.
- The group by clauses prevent the LEFT JOINs from expanding the result set via cartesian product

---

This DDL will create a table with enough fields to show the query working without errors.

```
create table product_option(merchant_id int, product_id int);
create table package_2_product(merchant_id int, product_id int);
create table category_2_product(merchant_id int, product_id int, category_id int);
create table product_image(merchant_id int, product_id int, is_default int,
    thumbnail int, thumbnail_width int, thumbnail_height int, title int, alt int);
create table product(merchant_id int, product_id int, in_stock_msg int,
    out_stock_msg int, param int, rank int, product_name int);
```

Comment: The above query is causing an error...  Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'p1.merchant_id' in 'on clause', which I believe is being caused by the derived tables in the left join clauses.  Did some googling haven't really come up with the reason for this.  Maybe because the group by clause is being used.

Comment: @Aglystas / I have checked many times and **cannot** see where I have used `p1.merchant_id`

Comment: Oh, sorry.  That particular comment I had tweaked your sql a little bit.  The same thing happens with p1.product_id in either of the left join (SELECT...) p1 or left join (SELECT...) p2 sections of your statement.

Comment: @Aglystas / I added a compatible table structure (all columns are int) and tested the query

Comment: I added your query to the original post, with 2 changes.  The product_option_id is what is being grabbed in the LEFT JOIN (SELECT...) p1, which also was changed in the COALESCE statement.

Comment: @Aglystas / Can you please list the fields for the table product_option? Is product_option.product_option_id = product.product_id? If not, changing product_id to product_option_id in the first LEFT JOIN subquery doesn't make sense

Comment: The original sql wasn't set up the way you created your sql so I changed it to what the original CASE statement was attempting to do (I didn't really look into the functionality of COALESCE).  Anyway the 2 separate sql statements in the CASE statement are used only to determine if some options exist (could be as product options from the product_options table, could be as packaging options from the package_2_product table).  As the original script is set up it simply looks to get returned integers and unions them.  If one or more integers are there then options_exist field is set to 1.

Comment: @Aglystas / Exactly, so use product_id as I have shown. There is no reason to use product_option_id.

Comment: So the sql you have does work but it returns a different number of records than the original query, so they must be different in some way, I posted the DDL for the product_option and package _2_product table above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS p.*, 
                           CASE p.in_stock_msg 
                             WHEN '' THEN 'In stock' 
                             ELSE p.in_stock_msg 
                           END     AS in_stock_msg, 
                           CASE p.out_stock_msg 
                             WHEN '' THEN '' 
                             ELSE p.out_stock_msg 
                           END     AS out_stock_msg, 
                           CASE 
                             WHEN Isnull(po.product_option_id) 
                                  AND Isnull(p2p.product_id) THEN 0 
                             ELSE 1 
                           END     AS options_exist, 
                           i.thumbnail, 
                           i.thumbnail_width, 
                           i.thumbnail_height, 
                           i.title AS thumbnail_title, 
                           i.alt   AS thumbnail_alt 
FROM   product p 
       INNER JOIN category_2_product c2p 
         ON p.merchant_id = c2p.merchant_id 
            AND p.product_id = c2p.product_id 
            AND c2p.category_id = 84 
       LEFT JOIN product_image i 
         ON p.merchant_id = i.merchant_id 
            AND p.product_id = i.product_id 
            AND i.is_default = 1 
       LEFT JOIN product_option po 
         ON po.merchant_id = 116 
            AND po.product_id = p.product_id 
       LEFT JOIN package_2_product p2p 
         ON p2p.merchant_id = 116 
            AND p2p.product_id = p.product_id 
WHERE  p.merchant_id = 116 
       AND Find_in_set('live', p.param) > 0 
       AND Find_in_set('wholesale-only', p.param) = 0 
GROUP  BY p.prduct_id 
ORDER  BY p.rank, 
          p.product_name 
LIMIT  0, 50;
```

you will need index on both tables for

- (merchant_id,product_id)